# Dynamic API Path as per Environment in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

```
interface GetDeatails {

    @GET("/details/v1/item/{value}")
    suspend fun eventDetails(
        @Path("value") value: String
    ): Response<DetailsResponseJson>

}
```

I need to add a condition based on the Environment of my project, if Environment is set as Development then API will be

> @GET("/details/v1/item/{value}")

and for others, it will be

> @GET("/details/v2/item/{value}")

how I can put an if-else condition in the interface or any other way I can achieve it?

Answer (score -1):

in your `Build.gradle(App)` add

```
buildTypes{

stageDebug {
debuggable true
buildConfigField "String", "URL", "\"https://your.url/api/\"" 
}
debug {
buildConfigField "String", "URL", "\"https://your.url/api/\""
} 
release {
buildConfigField "String", "URL", "\"https://your.url/api/\""
}
}
```

This is how I change stage debug release etc
and now in your network module where you have defined your base URLs just

```
const val baseURL = BuildConfig.URL
```

Comment: i want to change the API path only not the BASE URL

Comment: just put api paths like development APi path in some constant in stage api path in other constant and put paths in gradle.build the way I told you and then in your api path use BuildConfig.URL in that URL your paths will be there and android studio will change it according to environment